# How many window objects will a page having two iframes contain?

Tags: html, iframe

How many window objects will a page having two iframes contain?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp) site:

> The window object represents an open window in a browser.
>   If a document contain frames ( tags), the browser creates one window object for the HTML document, and one additional window object for each frame.

That means it could contain as much window object as there are iframes.